# cmake: execute cmake commands at install time

Tags: c++, linux, cmake

I have the following lines that execute with out problem when I have them as they are in CMakeLists.txt main file.

```
set (git_cmd git)
set (git_arg rev-parse --verify HEAD )
message(STATUS \"git cmd: ${git_cmd}\")
execute_process(COMMAND ${git_cmd} ${git_arg}
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}
  RESULT_VARIABLE git_result
  OUTPUT_VARIABLE git_ver)

message(STATUS \"git ver[${git_result}]: ${git_ver}\")
```

and I get the following output when I execute cmake

```
 -- "gitcmd:git"
 -- "gitver[0]:3268845bbbda4af12c951d75c25913d014da48ef
```

But what I really want is to execute that orders at install time, when I will execute "make install"

Thus, I enclose those LINES inside install: as install( CODE " LINES " )

```
install( CODE 
                "
set (git_cmd git)
set (git_arg rev-parse --verify HEAD )
message(STATUS \"git cmd: ${git_cmd}\")
execute_process(COMMAND ${git_cmd} ${git_arg}
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}
  RESULT_VARIABLE git_result
  OUTPUT_VARIABLE git_ver)

message(STATUS \"git ver[${git_result}]: ${git_ver}\")
        "
)
```

However, the output when I execute "make install" seems to indicate thar git_cmd was not set

```
-- git cmd: 
CMake Error at cmake_install.cmake:196 (execute_process):
  execute_process given COMMAND argument with no value.
```

What I am doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Just to be sure: you understand that his means ... in order to **install** your product, one needs access to your **git** repository? In other words: this install is for developers only?

Comment: @GhostCat, since install step implies having run cmake before, it really makes absolutely no difference. If this is published, it will need an _alternate_ approach for finding the version from something that will be included in the published bundle. But whether the command is at configure time or install time makes no difference as they both run on the same machine.

Answer (score 3):

You are setting the variables inside the install script, but expanding them already in the configure script!

There are four options how you can fix it:

1. Decide and hardcode the values at configure time:

   ```
   set (git_cmd git)
   set (git_arg "rev-parse --verify HEAD")
   install( CODE 
                   "
   message(STATUS \"git cmd: ${git_cmd}\")
   execute_process(COMMAND ${git_cmd} ${git_arg}
     WORKING_DIRECTORY \${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}
     RESULT_VARIABLE git_result
     OUTPUT_VARIABLE git_ver)

   message(STATUS \"git ver[\${git_result}]: \${git_ver}\")
           "
   )
   ```
2. Escape the snippet correctly:

   ```
   install( CODE 
                   "
   set (git_cmd git)
   set (git_arg rev-parse --verify HEAD )
   message(STATUS \"git cmd: \${git_cmd}\")
   execute_process(COMMAND \${git_cmd} \${git_arg}
     WORKING_DIRECTORY \${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}
     RESULT_VARIABLE git_result
     OUTPUT_VARIABLE git_ver)

   message(STATUS \"git ver[\${git_result}]: \${git_ver}\")
           "
   )
   ```
3. Set the variables in advance anyway, but expand them only at install time too. I am not sure whether they have to be in cache for that, but I suspect they do, so I add that:

   ```
   set (git_cmd git CACHE "" INTERNAL)
   set (git_arg rev-parse --verify HEAD CACHE "" INTERNAL)
   install( CODE 
                   "
   message(STATUS \"git cmd: \${git_cmd}\")
   execute_process(COMMAND \${git_cmd} \${git_arg}
     WORKING_DIRECTORY \${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}
     RESULT_VARIABLE git_result
     OUTPUT_VARIABLE git_ver)

   message(STATUS \"git ver[\${git_result}]: \${git_ver}\")
           "
   )
   ```
4. Instead of trying to get the quoting right, use the [`install(SCRIPT`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html#custom-installation-logic) form and put the commands in a separate file.

Note that:

1. In both cases I escaped the `$` in the last line, because those variables are always only defined inside the script and
2. I also escaped the `${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}`, but I am not completely certain the cache is loaded. If it is not, you'll have to escape it as `\"${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}\"` instead (and hope there will be no `"`s in the value).
3. Also in the first case I put the `git_arg` value in quotes, because a list would expand separated with `;`s and that would not read back correctly.

Due to the problems with special characters when reparsing I would **NOT** recommend the first option.